# Beginner in Java - Controlling output - Generating Asterix

Tags: java, whitespace, drjava

I am having difficulties with completing this program. I am trying to make a program that creates asteriks, but then makes it into a triangle.

This is what I have already.

```
public class 12345 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 0;
        int spaces = n;
        int ast;

        System.out.println("Please enter a number from 1 - 50 and I will draw a triangle with these *");

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        n = keyboard.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            ast = 2 * i + 1;

            for (int j = 1; j <= spaces + ast; j++) {
                if (j <= spaces)
                    System.out.print(' ');
                else
                    System.out.print('*');
            }

            System.out.println();
            spaces--;
        }
    }
}
```

It is creating the asteriks, but how would I be able to continue them where they make a triangle... so they get bigger as they go, and then back smaller...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: class name starting with number is allowed?????

Comment: Do u want to make structure like rhombus?

Comment: start with creating a `Right angled triangle`.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving

```
int spaces = n;
```

to AFTER the value of `n` is read from stdin.

This solves half your problem and hopefully gets you on the right track.

Comment: That would solve just a half of a diamond (top triangle will be printed)

Comment: Yes, but since this is likely homework I just wanted to nudge him in the right direction.  But you are right; I will update my answer to be more explicit about it.

Comment: it already prints out half of the triangle. I am just trying to teach myself how to make it where it creates the whole triangle.

Answer (score 0):

I added a few things to your code and got it to print the full triangle, where the number input in the scanner will be the number of asterisks printed in the bottom row. I.e. if the input is 3, the triangle will be two rows of 1->3; if the input is 5 then the triangle will be 3 rows of 1->3->5, and so on.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int ast;
        int reverse = 1;

        System.out.println("Please enter a number from 1 - 50 and I will draw a triangle with these *");

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int spaces = keyboard.nextInt();


        for (int i = 0; i < spaces; i++) {
            ast = 2 * i + 1;

            for (int j = 1; j <= spaces + ast; j++) {
                if (j <= spaces) {
                    System.out.print(' ');
                } else {
                    System.out.print('*');}
                if (j > spaces + ast) {
                    for (int k = 0; k < spaces-(reverse-1); k++) {
                        System.out.print(' ');
                    }
                }
                int k = 0;
                reverse++;

            }

            System.out.println();
            spaces--;
        }
    }
}
```

I added another if statement after your if-else that triggers when the variable j exceeds the first loop condition. This triggers another loop that makes the output lines symmetrical by essentially repeating your first if statement.

I hope this helps =)